# HADOOP "ssh: Could not resolve hostname <hostname>: nodename nor servname provided, or not known"

Tags: hadoop, ssh

I am trying to install hadoop in pseudo distributed mode in my Mac.
When I am starting start-dfs.sh , I get the following error:

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
Starting datanodes
Starting secondary namenodes [<hostname>]
<hostname>: ssh: Could not resolve hostname <hostname>: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
2021-11-02 19:49:31,023 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

What is it that I am missing here ?

Comment: `<hostname>` is not a valid hostname. Is this literally the output you get? If you have replaced this string, then you can replicate the problem with `ssh` command directly, which means you didn't correctly create a passwordless SSH key

Comment: <hostname> I kept it to mask the information . ssh localhost works properly

Comment: But does `ssh $(hostname -f)` work?

Comment: no , it fails with the same error

Comment: Exactly... So, you need to `ssh-copy-id $(hostname -f)`

Comment: ssh-copy-id $(hostname -f) also failed with the same error

Comment: Well, something in your hostname is invalid (A space character, for example). You could try to `sudo vi /etc/hosts`, to modify the hosts file but I wouldn't recommend it

Comment: In general, my recommendation would be to use Docker, not mess with host files or settings - https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop (this way, we can actually reproduce any problems you get)

Comment: Also, I don't think Hadoop works on M1 macs anyway, if that's what you have